# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mariadb

Есть поле, в него вводится 48 значений, всех их через POST надо передать в базу, хочу сделать это посредством php, но при попытке вноса более трех значений, вылетает такая ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES ( 5, 7, 200, 20 )' at line 6".

Если же ввожу 3 значения - они заносятся в базу без заминов. Использую 7.0 php, mariadb.
Имеется ли какой то лимит в конфиге, который можно сменить, или другое решение проблемы?

Comment: А каков должен быть запрос? Судя по алерту ошибка в наименовании одного из полей перед скобкой. Или его внесли в строку неправильно или лишняя скобка, или имя поля совпадает с наименованием команды sql и не экранировано. В общем масса вариантов

Comment: Все правильно в синтаксисе, он такой же как и у трех полей которые проходят спокойно, если их трое, если больше - не проходит.

Comment: Так может там и не хватает четвертого имени поля?

Comment: всего хватает, я не знаю почему так, но сделал отдельные запросы под каждое поле, работает вроде, но теперь с SELECT трабл, без логов))

Comment: Можно ли привести всю строчку, где происходит добавление? На php.